# Loading Classes From Static Library in D

Tags: class, static-libraries, d, static-linking

I read how to load functions from a static library from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366323/6123767

But I need to load a class from the static library, not just a function, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

classes are not actually a thing in exported binaries. They are just a fancy struct basically. And structs are basically just the layout of memory with data. Libraries mostly only contain functions.

So what you actually want to do is creating a class containing the member function declarations and adding the member variables in it like this:

library/somelib.d:

```d
module somelib;

class Foo
{
    private long member;

    this(long n)
    {
        member = n * 2;
    }

    int func(int x)
    {
        return cast(int) (x + member);
    }
}
```

wrapper/somelib.d:

```d
module somelib; // module names need to match!

class Foo
{
    private long member;
    this(long n);
    int func(int x);
}
```

app.d:

```d
module app;
import std.stdio;
import somelib;

void main()
{
    Foo foo = new Foo(4);
    writeln("foo: ", foo);
    writeln("func: ", foo.func(5));
}
```

Compile library with `dmd -lib library/somelib.d -ofsomelib.a` (or .lib on windows)

Compile executable with `dmd app.d -Iwrapper somelib.a -ofapp` (or .lib/.exe on windows)

I did `-Iwrapper` instead of specifying the filename so the module names can match the file/folder paths because the module name of wrapper/somelib.d **must** match the module name of library/somelib.d because thats how function names are mangled in D.